# React: Fetching data using useEffect and gettting .map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, fetch

I have this code:

```
    const App = () => {
      const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
    
      const getRecipes = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`);
        const data = response.json();
        setRecipes(data);
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        getRecipes();
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div className=`App`>
          <ul>
            {recipes.map((recipe) => (
              <li key={recipe.objectID}>
                <li>{recipe.title}</li>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

When doing npm start I get

> TypeError: recipes.map is not a function

error.

Don't know what is wrong, if I change the code to not use async/await but fetch .then() it works.
Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add await before json(), because the return value [is a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)

```
const data = await response.json();
```